# Apache can't compile header set regex

Tags: apache-2.4, regex, apache2

I have a very simple thing:
`RequestHeader edit X-Forwarded-User CORP\\(.*) $1`

Apache 2.4.18 on ubuntu says it can't compile header edit regex?

How can I troubleshoot this? Or better yet, how to fix that?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work with a backslash. I worked around it by using ````RequestHeader edit X-Forwarded-User ^CORP. "" ````

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue.  You can use a unicode hex character to represent the backslash.  Example:

```
RequestHeader edit X-Forwarded-User "^.*\x{005C}" ""
```